# Deinite Integral, evaluation of integrated expression

Tags: calculus, limits

When solving one of the assignments, I come across the following expression:

$$\left[-\frac{x}{2\lambda e^{\lambda x^2}}\right]^{\infty}_0$$

Where $\lambda$ is just a constant.

And I am not quite sure how to evaluate it correctly. Can I use L'Hôpital's rule here and say that, for the infinity part:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} -\frac{1}{4\lambda^2 xe^{\lambda x^2}}$$ which is a zero. So my expression is actually zero?

Comment: you are right. Notice that $e^{\lambda x^2}$ grows faster than $x$, then the ratio goes to $0$. This is true when $\lambda > 0$. On the other hand, if $\lambda < 0$, then the limit is $\infty$, since $x$ grows faster than $e^{\lambda x^2}$.

Comment: The problem did not specify whether lambda is a positive or a negative constant hmm

Comment: Then your result depends on $\lambda$